# VB6 Application - Runtime Error 429 : ActiveX Component Can't Create Object on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standart

Tags: vb6, runtime-error, activex, windows-server-2008-r2

I got **Runtime Error 429 : ActiveX Component Can't Create Object** at vb6 aplication running on **Windows Server 2008 r2 standart edition x64** - fresh install on Virtual PC.

I can run it on Windows 7, 10 and Windows Server 2003 with no problem using the same steps

1. Copying program folder
2. Register all dll and ocx files with admin cmd using %systemroot%/syswow64/regsvr32

I used a tool named "listdlls.exe", I compared what DLL and OCX files the app loads on Windows 7 and on Windows Server 2008 r2 - there are NO missing files. Just these 10 files that have different versions:

```
ntdll.dll on Windows 7 (6.1.7601.17514) and on Windows Server 2008 r2 (6.1.7601.23572)

kernelbase.dll on Windows 7 (6.1.7601.17514) and on Windows Server 2008 r2 (6.1.7601.23572)

advapi32.dll on Windows 7 (6.1.7601.17514) and on Windows Server 2008 r2 (6.1.7601.23572)

ole32.dll on Windows 7 (6.1.7601.17514) and on Windows Server 2008 r2 (6.1.7601.23392)

msctf.dll on Windows 7 (6.1.7600.16385) and on Windows Server 2008 r2 (6.1.7601.23572)

oleaut32.dll on Windows 7 (6.1.7601.17514) and on Windows Server 2008 r2 (6.1.7601.23569)

cryptsp.dll on Windows 7 (6.1.7600.16385) and on Windows Server 2008 r2 (6.1.7601.23471)

crypt32.dll on Windows 7 (6.1.7601.17514) and on Windows Server 2008 r2 (6.1.7601.23566)

asycfilt.dll on Windows 7 (6.1.7601.17514) and on Windows Server 2008 r2 (6.1.7601.23569)

olepro32.dll on Windows 7 (6.1.7601.17514) and on Windows Server 2008 r2 (6.1.7601.23452)
```

All other files that the app is using are the same version and size! So there are no other differences.

The program was ran as Administrator under Account set as Administrator.

I set my DEP (Data Execution Prevention) to 0

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64>wmic OS Get DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy
>
> DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy
>
> 0

Also I disabled UAC (User Account Control)

Any ideas? Are the version differences enough to cause this, or is there something else I'm missing?

Cheers!

Comment: ...did you get listdlls.exe to show COM references...??? BTW, just guessing: you could try to run a MDAC installer...

Answer (score 0):

Please use `ProcessMonitor` in order to identify which COM component was not found by your VB6 program on your Windows Server 2008 r2 standart edition x64.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx

Comment: I used this tool also there is nothing with status NOT FOUND or DENIED

Comment: Other possibility is that your COM components were found but where not able to be loaded. Still with `ProcessMonitor`, did you find any issue with DLL loading? Maybe some of your COM components rely also on some DLL which could not be loaded.